# How can I customise root partition (/) volume size in VM ( Centos7) creation using Packer?

Tags: centos, partition, lvm

I'm creating a vmware machine(`"type": "vmware-iso",`) using `packer`. By default it creates `/`(root) partition with size appx `40 GB`(not sure why? default ?). Now I am struggling to find out a way through which I can provide custome size of `/` root partition (filesystem - `/dev/mapper/centos-root`) so that vm comes up with this size root size.

I am aware that machine info can be given to `vmx_data`. But I could not find a `key` that could take custom volume size for `/`.

I also got to know that volume size can be provided in `preseed.conf` file during packer run. But not sure if this is the right approach or is it the only approach. Resizing can be done after installation, but looks like that approach would be gunned down.